# How to make my custom TaskScheduler the default one

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have my own implementation of `TaskScheduler`. The main reason for its existence is that it will set processor core affinity to the thread running my task.

When I use it in the following manner:

```
var myTaskSceduler = new MyTaskScheduler(4);
var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(myTaskSceduler);
taskFactory.StartNew(DoSomething);
```

the affinity works fine, the task will run only on the specified core.

How can I change `Task.Factory` or `Task.Factory.Scheduler` so my scheduler will be the default one whenever

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew()
```

is being called?

Comment: You can't. `Task.Factory` and `TaskScheduler.Default` are backed by static readonly fields. The only way that a `TaskFactory`'s default scheduler can be set is via its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just create your own static method, `MyTask.StartNew()`? Don't you have to specify the affinity as a parameter anyway?

In any case, the task factory should use the same scheduler you're in when you call `StartNew`. So if you do that on a task on the proper scheduler, it should work just fine. This really depends on how you handle your processing scheduling etc, but I assume you're going to be context dependent anyway if you're not going to be passing the affinity anywhere.

Comment: actually I need it so all the tasks created by my async/await methods will be scheduled using my scheduler.
There is no parameter to pass, the affinity is hardcoded for the moment

Comment: @HadarGrubman Ah. In that case, just make sure you're doing the awaiting in the proper parent task (which was started on the scheduler you want), and it should work just fine.